# Zeppelin dynamic form: z.input() throws 'AttributeError' error in one notebook but not the other

Tags: forms, apache-zeppelin

I am learning zeppelin. I have created two notebooks which have same setting (the default interpreter binding is python). My problem is that z.input() works well in one notebook but the other throws AttributeError:

I enter exactly code: print(z.input("greeting", "Hello World"))

Here is the detailed error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-3719661631556809998.py", line 283, in 
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-3719661631556809998.py", line 276, in 
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'input'

Answer (score 0):

What version of Zeppelin are you using and can you post here your python interpreter session settings? Without further details I can only guess, that you have declared a string variable named 'z' in some other part of your zeppelin. It can be in a different paragraph in the same note that throws you an error. Eg.:

Paragraph #1:

```
%python
z = 'foo'
```

Paragraph #2:

```
%python
print(z.input("greeting", "Hello World"))
```

Running this note paragraph after paragraph will throw you the same error in paragraph #2. But with different zeppelin versions and python interpreter settings it may occur in other situations too.